# Has the open-source roadmap been discontinued after WSO API Manager 4.2.0 version?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I checked the WSO2 APIM Github, and it appears that there have been no further tags or releases since the 4.2.0 release in March 2023. Has the open-source roadmap been discontinued after version 4.2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The new version (4.3.0) is planned to be released at the end of this quarter or the beginning of the next quarter.